# Cannot install Selenium IDE in with Firefox Developer Edition

Tags: selenium-ide

I am using Firefox Developer Edition 44.0a2 (2015-12-03) tried to install Selenium IDE, it does not install. how can i install it?

However, standard Firefox works fine with latest selenium IDE.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the error you are getting while installing the IDE. I have the latest selenium IDE on the same edition. It works fine for me.

Comment: I was trying to install from http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/
>> released version 2.9.0 released on 09/Mar/2015
it says 'could not installed as file appear to be corrupt'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I did to install the IDE:

1. Open https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/selenium-ide/ with Firefox
2. Click on Add to firefox
3. Click on install once the file is downloaded

After installing,restart the browser and it should work.
The version of IDE I'm using is 2.9.1 and the Firefox developer edition 44.0a2